# Exception in fetchPairData() : call revert exception in method getReserves()

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, swap, web3js, binance-smart-chain

I am trying to call the "fetchPairData" function (https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/SDK/fetcher/) but I am getting the following error.

```
Error: call revert exception (method="getReserves()", errorSignature=null, errorArgs=[null], reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.1.2)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\*\Desktop\ProyectoTransaccion\v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:180:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\*\Desktop\ProyectoTransaccion\v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:189:20)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (C:\Users\*\Desktop\ProyectoTransaccion\v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\interface.js:289:23)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*\Desktop\ProyectoTransaccion\v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:329:56)
    at step (C:\Users\*\Desktop\ProyectoTransaccion\v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\*\Desktop\ProyectoTransaccion\v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\*\Desktop\ProyectoTransaccion\v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'getReserves()',
  errorSignature: null,
  errorArgs: [ null ],
  address: '0x80f836E71a6C92acebf6A49ad39038609c780070',
  args: [],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x0902f1ac',
    to: '0x80f836E71a6C92acebf6A49ad39038609c780070'
  }
}
```

Relevant code:

```
const {ChainId, Token, TokenAmount, Fetcher, Pair, Route, Trade, TradeType, Percent} = require('@pancakeswap-libs/sdk');

    const INPUT_TOKEN = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET,InputTokenAddr, 18);
    const OUTPUT_TOKEN = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, OutputTokenAddr, 18);


    try {
        
        pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(INPUT_TOKEN, OUTPUT_TOKEN, provider);
        
    } catch (ex)
    {

        console.log("Debug.INPUT_TOKEN: " + JSON.stringify(INPUT_TOKEN));
        console.log("Debug.OUTPUT_TOKEN: " + JSON.stringify(OUTPUT_TOKEN));
        console.log("Debug.provider: " + JSON.stringify(provider));
        console.log(ex)
        pair = null;
    }
```

Debug:

```
Debug.INPUT_TOKEN: {"decimals":18,"chainId":56,"address":"0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"}
Debug.OUTPUT_TOKEN: {"decimals":18,"chainId":56,"address":"0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56"}
Debug.provider: {"_isProvider":true,"_events":[],"_emitted":{"block":-2},"formatter":{"formats":{"transaction":{},"transactionRequest":{},"receiptLog":{},"receipt":{},"block":{},"blockWithTransactions":{},"filter":{},"filterLog":{}}},"anyNetwork":false,"_networkPromise":{},"_maxInternalBlockNumber":-1024,"_lastBlockNumber":-2,"_pollingInterval":4000,"_fastQueryDate":0,"connection":{"url":"https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"},"_nextId":45,"_eventLoopCache":{"detectNetwork":null,"eth_chainId":null},"_network":{"chainId":56,"name":"unknown"}}
```

I have verified that the swap works correctly in the pancakeswap web interface. It does not indicate route on the web, so it seems that it is a direct swap.

With other tokens the call returns what is expected. For example with the pair WBNB, BUSD.

[I found for this error on another site with this comment](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/3771)

> I faced the same issue and the problem was that I was trying to fetch
> price for a pool that did not exist.

The pool exists. It has liquidity and it is also direct, it does not require a route.

Answer (score 5):

The call revert exception happens when

- the client doesn't receive a response

  *(no contract deployed on the address)*
- or when the contract code performs a revert.

  ```
  pragma solidity ^0.8;

  contract MyContract {
      function foo() external view {
          revert();
      }
  }
  ```

  *(Can also be when you're calling an undefined function and there's no `fallback()` in the contract)*

---

Your question doesn't specify on which network you tried to perform the call, but there's no contract on the failing address on both [mainnet](https://bscscan.com/address/0x80f836E71a6C92acebf6A49ad39038609c780070) and [testnet](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x80f836E71a6C92acebf6A49ad39038609c780070).

So either your client app is trying to call this non-existing contract directly, or some contract in the chain of calls is trying to call it.

```
transaction: {
    data: '0x0902f1ac',
    to: '0x80f836E71a6C92acebf6A49ad39038609c780070'
}
```

Comment: I call Fetcher.fetchPairData with the parameters that comes out in "Debug:" in my question (2 tokens and provider) I do not understand why in the trace of  the error of fetchPairData a contract that does not exist has appeared if I have indicated as input the addresses of the tokens that exist (check "Debug:"). The call is in mainnet (ChainId.MAINNET)

Comment: It's most likely caused by the `Fetcher` contract that fails to call `getReserves()` on the non-existing `0x80f836...` contract. What is the `Fetcher` address?

Comment: In the code there is only one other reference to "Fetcher", it is this: -> const {ChainId, Token, TokenAmount, Fetcher, Pair, Route, Trade, TradeType, Percent} = require('@pancakeswap-libs/sdk');

Comment: It seems that the `address` field (comming from `Pair`; [GitHub link](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancakeswap-sdk-v1/blob/master/src/fetcher.ts#L70-L71)) is the incorrect `0x80f836...`. It might require some Pancakeswap SDK configuration but this is not my area of expertise, so I'm not sure what to configure. But my educated guess is that the `Pair` is using some default or incorrectly configured value.

Comment: Very accurate assessment @PetrHejda, `Pair.getAddress` returns wrong Pair address for many tokens for sure. @user2983041 were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @NamanyayGoel why for sure? Is that because of some reasonable reason, or because of bugs in the sdk?

Answer (score -1):

me also facing the same issue for some tokens but i'm sure there is some issue in our end because some tokens have different routes for swapping. If token have different routes not direct swap that tokens will get same error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uajZ1.png)